# Find a partiular strings in each row of an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an Excel sheet where the data is presented like an "Input Sheet". I need to search using VBscript if T1 or T2 is present in each row. If it is found then the "Task compdate" column should copy value from its immediate "Stardate" column of the next task if any.

***Input Sheet:***

```
 Activity        Task1    Task1 Stardate   Task1 Compdate     Task2     Task2 Stardate   Task2 Compdate   Task3     Task3 Stardate   Task3 Compdate

A1                T1       02/01/2012                           T1       04/01/2011                         T3         09/02/2011

A2                T2       02/01/2012                           T2       04/01/2011                         T3         09/02/2011

A3                T1       02/01/2012                           T4       04/01/2011                         T3         09/02/2011
```

***Output Sheet:***

```
 Activity        Task1    Task1 Stardate   Task1 Compdate     Task2     Task2 Stardate   Task2 Compdate   Task3     Task3 Stardate   Task3 Compdate

A1                T1       02/01/2012        04/01/2011         T1        04/01/2011       09/02/2011       T3         09/02/2011

A2                T2       02/01/2012        04/01/2011         T2        04/01/2011       09/02/2011       T3         09/02/2011

A3                T1       02/01/2012        04/01/2011         T4        04/01/2011                        T3         09/02/2011
```

***Update Code:***

```
IntRow6=2

Do While objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1).Value <> ""

DataCount=0
 For DataCount=0 to UBound(VMHArray)

  Set rSearch = objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1).EntireRow
  Set rFound = rSearch.Find(VMHArray(DataCount))
     
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

                 adrFirst = rFound.Address

               Do  

                   objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,rFound.Column + 2)= objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,rFound.Column + 5)
                   Set rFound = rSearch.FindNext(rFound)

               Loop Until rFound.Address = adrFirst
       End If
    
 Next

IntRow6=IntRow6+1
Loop
```

Comment: Can you please double confirm if you are using 'vbscript' or 'vba'? So it makes things easier for us to assist you :)

Comment: @user1878162 - please consolidate your sample wrt T3 and T4.

Comment: For T1 and T2 i want their respective compdate column should have values. But except T1 and T2, any tasks need to be skipped by the script.

Comment: @bonCodigo This is the sample only.What i tabulated here. In my actual sheet there are 3000 rows and 250 columns carrying such input sheet raw data,on which i need to run through the logic as i mentioned in the post description.Thus i need an script in VB.

Comment: @user1878162 - so why does A3/T3 in the input sheet changes to A3/T1 in the output sheet?

Comment: Thanks to show me the data discrepancy.I just corrected the Tabular Input data. Please check.

Comment: @user1878162 And now what is your effort so far? Or is this you free scripting source (looking at all your other questions as well). Please see the FAQ and act accordingly.

Comment: -1 The question remains as to **why** you are using vbscript when you will need to automate Excel to get anything approaching a solution. Why not VBA when you accept VBA answers? In addition, I see you are still not using the Excel tag. Finally, you have not included even one line of your own code.

Comment: Please see my update above.I was facing some issue with this,Thus i didn't posted my erroneous code.Now I updated that above.Why you rated my Question down?

Comment: Now that we see your code i'm pretty much sure you are using VBA instead of vbscript...

Comment: No.I am using VBScript only.They are pretty much same to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update Code:***

```
IntRow6=2

Do While objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1).Value <> ""

DataCount=0
 For DataCount=0 to UBound(VMHArray)

  Set rSearch = objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1).EntireRow
  Set rFound = rSearch.Find(VMHArray(DataCount))
     
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

                 adrFirst = rFound.Address

               Do  

                   objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,rFound.Column + 2)= objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,rFound.Column + 5)
                   Set rFound = rSearch.FindNext(rFound)

               Loop Until rFound.Address = adrFirst
       End If
    
 Next

IntRow6=IntRow6+1
Loop
```